# How to add double forward slash in a string without commenting out in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, escaping, sublimetext3

I would like to create a string but when I create the string variable the double forward slash comments out the rest of the line. How do I create a string without commenting out part of the string?

example:

```
var linkVariable = "http://free.clipartof.com/176-Free-Cartoon-Owl-Clipart.jpg"
```

Everything after the `//` gets commented out.

Comment: It doesn't get commented out for me. I just executed that exact line in Chrome and it was fine. Are you sure it's not just an error in your editor's syntax highlighting? If it's really causing you grief, you can always escape the slashes with \ like so: `"http:\/\/...etc"`

Comment: `var linkVariable = "http:/"+"/free.clipartof.com/176-Free-Cartoon-Owl-Clipart.jpg"`

Comment: You're right it does work. I should have tested it before I posted this. Sublime greyed out everything starting at the forward slashes so that confused me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a string in javascript by putting the string inside quotations:

```
var answer = "It's alright";
var answer = "He is called 'Johnny'";
var answer = 'He is called "Johnny"';
```

Which you have correctly done.

What you are seeing is likely syntax highlighting from your code editor/IDE.

A good tool, as you are getting started, is jsfiddle.

I have set up a jsFiddle for you with the following code:

```js
var linkVariable = "http://free.clipartof.com/176-Free-Cartoon-Owl-Clipart.jpg"

document.getElementById('link').value = linkVariable;
```

```html
<input style="width:300px;" type="text" id="link"></input>
```

also available at

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/yte9f5yv/

Where you can see the value of your string variable in an input box.

Go take a look and play around creating the different types in javascript. I've learned a lot from isolating problems and testing it in an external environment!

Also, your code editor probably has settings that can be adjusted to fix this for you.

Edit: (since you are using Sublime Text)
In sublime text you can go to Preferences -> Browse Packages -> Javascript and find the file Comments.tmPreferences . You can then edit your comments preferences.